# If 130.0 mL of 3.0×10−3 M Na2SO4(aq) is saturated with CaSO4, how many grams of would be present in the solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry

If 130.0 mL of 3.0×10−3 M Na2SO4(aq) is saturated with CaSO4, how many grams of would be present in the solution? [Hint: Does the usual simplifying assumption hold?]

[image]

My answer is still wrong. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Your answer and method used appears to be correct. I don't see why it would be wrong.

Comment: "how many grams of would be present in the solution?" - how many grams of what? Are you sure it's CaSO4 and not Ca or SO4?